# Alternative ways of writing for loop of C++ in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, range

Today, I was solving one problem. Unfortunately, I got stuck at the end so I search for the solution on google, and found one written in the C++ language. When I was converting one to another, I noticed that the range function in Python doesn't have a condition argument.

```c
for(int i=5; i*i<=N; i=i+6)
```

My first solution:

```
for i in range(5,N+1,6):
    if (i*i<=N):
       break
```

My second solution:

```
i=5
while(i*i<=N):
   i+=6
```

If you have any solution, please suggest it.

Comment: Please post more details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Seems like you've already solved this "problem" with your while-loop.

Comment: `for i in range(5, int(sqrt(N))+1, 6)` is another option, but I think the `while` is better.

Comment: What is the motivation here? You've solved it already in the simplest possible way.

Comment: @Samwise seems like the `sqrt` will add to unnecessary computational cost. This problem doesn't need it.

Comment: I agree, but he asked about a way to embed the condition in the `range`, and that would be how to do it.  (Note that the computation may actually be cheaper with doing `sqrt` once vs doing `**2` N/6 times, depending on the value of `N`!)

Comment: Those solutions are both reasonable but I like the second a bit better - it shows the condition in the looping construct. Depending on what this `i` is used for in the loop, there may be other ways to do this. But from the information given, this is how it would be done in python. You could do `for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x*x<N, range(5,N+1,6)):`. It keeps the decision in the loop construct and would also work for a list comprension.

Comment: I want a one-line solution. that is the reason I ask for an alternative solution, thanks for replaying